# Angular2 passing values to other class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, angular

I am trying to make use of D3-charts in my NG2-app nad I have the"chart" up and running with hardcoded data. Im looking for a way to be able to pass data to the chart from another component. Here is the "parent"-component which contains the directive in which the graph gets displayed:

```
@Component({
  selector: "homeTest",
   properties: [ 'data' ]
})
@View({
  directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES, BarGraph],  
    template: `
  <h1 class="title">Angular 2</h1>
  <bar-graph>
  </bar-graph> 
  `

})
export class HomeTest {

  meter: any;
  consumption: any;
  elementRef: any;
  constructor() {}
```

Its from this component I fetch the data I want to use in the graph. Lets say it looks like this:

```
PassThisArrayToBarChart(){
var dataset = [ 
    { key: 0, value: 5 },
    { key: 1, value: 10 }
     ];


 //Pass this dataSet to Barchart somehow?
}
```

And here is the class where we have the D3-chart which need a dataset:

```
@Directive({
  selector:   'bar-graph',
})
class BarGraph {
  data: Array<number>;
  divs: any;
  dataset: any;
  constructor( 
    @Inject(ElementRef) elementRef: ElementRef,
    @Attribute('width') width: string,
    @Attribute('height') height: string) {

    var w = 600;
    var h = 250;

var dataset = [ 
    { key: 0, value: 5 },
    { key: 1, value: 10 }
     ];

...
```

As you can see here I have a hard-coded dataset which is working but how can this be replaced by a dataset passed from HomeTest?

Here is the rest of BarGraph if needed:

```
var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
                .domain(d3.range(dataset.length))
                .rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.05); 

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {return d.value;})])
                .range([0, h]);

var key = function(d) {
    return d.key;
};

//Create SVG element
var svg = d3.select("bar-graph")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);

//Create bars
svg.selectAll("rect")
   .data(dataset, key)
   .enter()
   .append("rect")
   .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return xScale(i);
   })
   .attr("y", function(d) {
        return h - yScale(d.value);
   })
   .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
   .attr("height", function(d) {
        return yScale(d.value);
   })
   .attr("fill", function(d) {
        return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d.value * 10) + ")";
   })



//Create labels
svg.selectAll("text")
   .data(dataset, key)
   .enter()
   .append("text")
   .text(function(d) {
        return d.value;
   })
   .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
   .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return xScale(i) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2;
   })
   .attr("y", function(d) {
        return h - yScale(d.value) + 14;
   })
   .attr("font-family", "sans-serif") 
   .attr("font-size", "11px")
   .attr("fill", "white");

  }
```

Update:

```
@Component({
  selector: "homeTest",
  properties: [ 'data' ]
})
@View({
  directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES, BarGraph],  

    template: `
  <h1 class="title">Angular 2 + d3</h1>
  <bar-graph [graphdata]="dataset">
  </bar-graph>
  `

})

    export class HomeTest {
      dataset: Array<Object> = [ 
        { key: 0, value: 5 },
        { key: 1, value: 10 }
      ];

      constructor() {}
```

BarGraph:

```
@Directive({
  selector:   'bar-graph',

})
export class BarGraph {
  @Input() graphdata;
  data: Array<number>;
  divs: any;
  dataset: any;
  constructor( 
    @Inject(ElementRef) elementRef: ElementRef,
    @Attribute('width') width: string,
    @Attribute('height') height: string) {

    var w = 600;
    var h = 250;

var dataset = this.graphdata; //graphData undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the data via a property of the element

```
<bar-graph [graphdata]="dataset">
```

So you will need this in the parent class

```
export class HomeTest {
  dataset: Array<Object> = [ 
    { key: 0, value: 5 },
    { key: 1, value: 10 }
  ];
```

And then pick it up in the component itself

```
class BarGraph {
    @Input() graphdata;
    constructor() {}
    afterViewInit() {
      var dataset = this.graphdata;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, im a bit confused though...I placed dataset: Array<object> in HomeTest as per your instruction.   Should not this mean that I need to set dataSet = graphData somewhere in BarGraph? When debugging BarGraph, this.graphdata is undefined.

Also, this line :
<bar-graph [graphdata]="dataset">
Is from the template in Hometest right?

Comment: I used different names for the same data so you could see what is called in the parent and what in the child. Have you added `{... Input ...}` to your angular2 import statement in `BarGraph`?

Comment: Yes, I added input, I added an update. I will keep trying. Thank you
But this.graphdata is supposed to contain the array from the parent right?

Comment: @user2915962 I think the constructor function is called earlier than data is passed down to the component.  Use the `afterViewInit` method instead and use `onChanges` if it is going to change again thereafter.

Comment: Thanks Simon! this.graphData existed in afterViewInit(). Everything is as it should now.

Comment: @user2915962, according to the [API docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/lifecycle_hooks/OnInit-interface.html), `onInit()` is called after a directive's/component's data-bound properties have been set, so it may be more appropriate than `afterViewInit()`.